# Configuring Twister on multiple node cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, ssh, mapreduce

The only instructions I found on how to set up Twister on multiple nodes, are [these](http://salsahpc.indiana.edu/tutorial/twister_install.htm#IV._Cluster).
I am quite a newbie to distributed programming and map reduce paradigm, so I could use some more detailed literature (tutorials, articles, examples, questions on stack overflow etc).

Let's say I have small cluster, containing two computers. Both computers can run a Twister application I wrote on the local host. They are connected within same LAN, with addresses e.g. `192.168.0.11` and `192.168.0.18`.
Let's say `192.168.0.11` will be **master** node - the one from which I would like to run my application. Let's call other computer **slave**.

Computers can communicate via SSH, without prompting password (master can do password-less SSH to slave and himself; slave can do password-less SSH to master and himself).

I also understood that on master node, one should name all IP nodes' addresses in the **$TWISTER_HOME/bin/nodes** file; so, in this case:

```
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.18
```

What is next? Are there some more configurations? Should something be changed on the slave computer's configuration? Should Narada and Twister be ran on both computers, or just on master?
These steps look quite blurry to me.

Also, I would very appreciate any related article or something of that kind.

Thank you.

Comment: are the OP and answerer both same with different account? Linkedin profiles provided in both about profile directs to [Branislava Šandrih](https://rs.linkedin.com/in/branislavasandrih)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On slave:

1. run narada (ip of that node)

On master:

2. run narada (both nodes)
3. run twister
4. run application